# Relations between slowly changing dimensions in a data warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse

I’m designing a data warehouse and am struggling to work out how I should be modelling this scenario. I’ve got Users stored in a Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2 table along these lines:

| UserKey | UserID | Language | EffectiveDate | ExpiryDate | IsCurrent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | EN | 2021-01-01 | 9999-12-3 | Y |
| 2 | 1002 | EN | 2021-07-31 | 2022-01-06 | N |
| 3 | 1002 | FR | 2022-01-06 | 9999-12-31 | Y |

And a Login fact table like:

| LoginKey | UserKey | LoginTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-12-25 15:00 |
| 12399 | 3 | 2022-01-31 18:00 |

Thereby allowing us to report on logins by date by user language setting at the time, etc.

Now I have to consider that each user may have one, none, or many concurrent subscriptions, which I was thinking of modelling in a Type 1 SCD thus:

| SubsKey | SubsID | SubsType | UserKey | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55501 | SBP501 | Premium | 2 | 2021-08-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 55502 | SBB123 | Bonus | 3 | 2022-01-31 | 2023-01-31 |

Is it right for one dimension table to reference the surrogate row key of another like this, or should it rather contain the UserID natural key? It seems unwieldy for the Subs table to have different UserKeys for the two concurrent Subscriptions for the same user like this. Or perhaps, when the third row was added to the Type 2 User table, should all the existing rows in Subs with UserKey=2 have been updated to UserKey=3?

The whole thing doesn't seem to fit comfortably into the classic snowflake pattern, which usually has the one-to-many relationship pointing the other way, as might be the case were Language to be a separate dimension table say, with a one-to-many relation on User.

### Edit

I'm wrestling with not only in the one-to-many example described (one user has many subscriptions) but also many-to-one relations between SCDT2 tables e.g. If the user's language was stored in a SCDT2 table, should the User dimension use reference the Language ID or the LanguageKey for Language table's current row?

Answer (score 0):

A subscription is a fact and so should be stored in a fact table - though you might also have a subscription dimension that holds attributes of a subscription such as its name.
You relate dimensions through fact tables, so your subscription fact would have FKs to Subscription, User, Date etc dimensions.

Relating dimensions directly to each other is called snowflaking and is, generally a bad design.

BTW for an SCD2 table, having the expiry date of one row the same as the effective date of the next row is not a good design. In your example, you would need business logic to define which row was active on 2022-01-06, whereas if a row expires on 2022-01-06 and the next row starts on 2022-01-07 there can be no confusion.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I hadn't heard snowflake schemas were inherently bad before, just sometimes harder to query. 

I don't quite perceive what makes a Subscription a fact instead of a dimension. What about a user's Country then, say, with details stored in a country dimension table and a Country Key in the User table? If I wanted just to query the number of users per country, I wouldn't be "relating dimensions through fact tables" then?

Comment: On your SCD2 dates point, I would have thought having one row start the very instant the previous one ends, (i.e. `[A, B)` inclusive start, exclusive end) was preferable as you only ever need to consider whether Effective <= DT < Expiry, whether or not DT contains a time component. With your approach there is always an ambiguous gap.

Comment: If country is an attribute of a user then you can include it in the user dimension. This doesn’t stop you also having an address/country dimension if you need it - a dimensional model is denormalised so you can have the same data in multiple tables, as long as there are good design reasons for doing so

Comment: SCD2: how would someone know that the logic is “Effective <= DT < Expiry” rather than “ Effective < DT <= Expiry”? If you have contiguous, rather than overlapping, dates this issue goes away

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, the last table looks like more close to SLCD Type 4 than Type 1.

Indeed, I agree that subscriptions might be a Fact table and have a Dimension table.
Perhaps, an SLCD Type 2 can be the best option for the subscriptions dimension table but adding a flag column to set the current/active subscription with his associated effective date.